# ASP .Net MVC Contoso University How to grab student details based off last name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to learn MVC and I'm following along with the Contoso University tutorial located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

I've successfully built a project that has a database with students, Courses, and Enrollments. Currently I have 3 models,

1. Course
2. Enrollment
3. Student

and 2 controllers

1. HomeController
2. StudentController

Currently my routing is the default routing you get with an MVC project.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

And this works well for grabbing student details based on StudentID

So the URL

http://localhost:49706/Student/Details/1

returns this
[image: Student Details]

This works great, but I'm trying to understand routing a bit more in depth. I want to create a new view that will display the student details based on LAST NAME rather than student ID. Yes I know that in the real world, this wouldn't be a good idea since last names aren't unique, but it's fine for this demonstration since my database won't be getting larger and I know all last names are currently unique.

First thing I did was create a new action result in my StudentController

```
public ActionResult Grab(string studentName)
{
    if(studentName == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Student student = db.Students.Find(studentName);
    if(student == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(student);
}
```

The second thing I did was right clicked on 'Grab' and added a view. I called the View name 'Grab'. Set the Template as 'List'. Set the Model Class as 'Student (ContosoUniversity.Models)'. and the DataContextClass to 'SchoolContext (ContosoUniversity.DAL)'.

[image: Add View]

When I call this
http://localhost:49706/Student/Grab

I get a 400 error just like I wrote in the controller. However when I try the following url

http://localhost:49706/Student/Grab/Alexander

I also get another 400 error. I'm not really sure what I left out. Can I get some help please.

Here is what my database looks like

[image: Database]

Again all I want to do is to be able to enter the following url
http://localhost:49706/Student/Grab/{LastName}

and have it display the details of the student with the matching last name.

Thank you for your time

EDIT

Updated ActionResult Grab

```
public ActionResult Grab(string studentName)
{
    if(studentName == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Student student = db.Students.Where(student => student.LastName.Contains(studentName)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (student == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(student);
}
```

Entire Student Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ContosoUniversity.DAL;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        private SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();

        // GET: Student
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Students.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Student/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        public ActionResult Grab(string studentName)
        {
            if(studentName == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Student student = db.Students.Where(student => student.LastName.Contains(studentName)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        // GET: Student/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Student/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "LastName, FirstMidName, EnrollmentDate")]Student student)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Students.Add(student);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        // GET: Student/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        // POST: Student/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var studentToUpdate = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (TryUpdateModel(studentToUpdate, "",
               new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName", "EnrollmentDate" }))
            {
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (DataException /* dex */)
                {
                    //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                }
            }
            return View(studentToUpdate);
        }

        // GET: Student/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }

        // POST: Student/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            db.Students.Remove(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to suggestions so far I've now got a page returning. However, no data is being loaded. Here is a photo
[image: Almost working]

Here is the code for the view

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Student

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Grab";
    }

    <h2>Grab</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstMidName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: What does the link to the Grab View on your view look like?

Comment: Hi can you send this code bcz i am also new to mvc. I don’t know how to get the student details by clicking on the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the routing. When you request `http://localhost:49706/Student/Grab/{LastName}` the parameter `studentName` is resolving to null, hence your BadRequestResponse.

The pattern in your url matches the default ASP.NET MVC route pattern, but it'll fail to bind the value for the parameter, so MVC will hit you controller and action properly but the parameter will be null.

**You have a couple of options:**

> Map a route

You can add this to your routing config file: `RouteConfig.cs` in `App_Start` directory:

```
//Add your own route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: null,
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{studentName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Grab", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This call should go before the call to map the default route. Now you'll be able to get the value for the studentName parameter from the  route data.

> Change the url

You can call the same action without adding a new route by requesting your page as:

```
http://localhost:49706/Student/Grab?studentName={LastName}
```

Here the parameter will be effectively handled.

Regarding fetching the student from the database I'd use this code in the action if just want to match by full last name:

```
public ActionResult Grab(string studentName)
{
    if (studentName == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var student = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LastName.ToLower() == studentName.ToLower());
    if (student == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    return View(student);
}
```

Let me know how it works for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks valuable. I will be trying this later. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The OP knows that using `LastName` is not unique.. but in this instance it is.. so why use `FirstOrDefault`.. if the `LastName` is unique.. there will only be 1 record with that specific `LastName`..

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid you're right. You could use SingleOrDefault in this particular case. Anyway this is not the OP problem. The problem is the routing so parameter studentName can not be populated. The fact that you use FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault in this case is irrelevant to OP's problem.

Comment: I know that it's irrelevant to the actual problem.. I just wanted to simply state that in scenarios where a developer wants to only return 1 object.. they should use `SingleOrDefault`.. just as good practice..

Comment: Ok then. Fair enough. :-)

Comment: Sorry if I came off offensive.. that wasn't my intention.. I was just looking and saw that.. so no offense intended.

Comment: I got an error when I did this. I updated added my own route and then updated my code in the action with what you supplied. This is what it gave me. 

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Student_46F139E8A1D422A31682B5D05024AE0BF96370A58B567A1317CF8DDBCA16D906', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ContosoUniversity.Models.Student]'.

Comment: This is almost working but there are just a few problems left. Please see my edits above. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @onTheInternet Sorry I did miss your comment. The issue in this case is that you used the List template when scaffolded the Grab view and then view is expecting an IEnumerable<Student> and you're passing only one instance of Student. Try repeating the scaffolding process using Details as your template instead of List.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been incredibly helpful and your reasoning very clear. I wish I could give you more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake :

`db.Students.Find(studentName); // This one expects an student object not string`

So you need to use `Where` linq extension so you can filter your students table by last name like this :

`Student student = db.Students.Where(student => student.LastName.Contains(studentName)).FirstOrDefault(); 
// Im using contains instead of equals to match substrings`

Comment: This gives me an error. "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>' to 'ContosoUniversity.Models.Student'. An explicit conversion exists (Are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @onTheInternet sorry I missed the `FirstOrDefault` part, what it does is to fetch the first result in our query or assign default student object if our list is empty

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i still have one more error now on. "A local or parameter named 'student' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"

Comment: @onTheInternet check the parameters and declaration if they have duplicate names

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm not sure where to look. Do you mean look in my student model? or in my actionResult in the student controller

Comment: in your controller, you can update your question to show the updated code so I can check

Comment: I've updated my post and I'm currently looking through my student controller.

Comment: @onTheInternet Found it! `Student student = db.Students.Where(student => student.LastName.Contains(studentName)).FirstOrDefault();` `student` variable was used also inside `Where` so we need to rename one of them. `Student student = db.Students.Where(stud => stud.LastName.Contains(studentName)).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: That cleared up my errors. But I'm still seeing a 400 error when I type in the following url http://localhost:49706/Student/Grab/Carson

Comment: There is no value to using `.Where` and `Contains`.. you can simplify what you've provided to just using `FirstOrDefault(student => student.LastName.ToLower() == studentName.ToLower())`.. really should be `.SingleOrDefault` since the OP is only trying to return 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying this from the `Index` view.. so since your `Grab` ActionResult is expecting a parameter called `studentName` (might want to rename to something that corresponds to lastName for maintainability purposes).. an action link on your `Index` view needs to look like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details by Last Name", "Grab", "Student", new{studentName = item.LastName}, null)
// I assume `item` because if it's in your Index view you are looping to get each user in their own row..
```

Since you understand that using a person's last name is a bad idea due to not being unique... but in this instance it is.. there is no need to use `.Contain()` method.. You are searching for **ONE** person, so you should use `.SingleOrDefault()`.

```
public ActionResult Grab(string studentName)
{
    // in my experience.. when you're checking a string variable to see if 
    // it is null.. use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace.. because even though what
    // you're using checks for null.. it doesn't check for white space..


    if(studentName == null) // so change this to if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(studentName))
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    Student student = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(student => student.LastName.ToLower() == studentName.ToLower()); // convert the comparison strings to all lower case.. hence the the `.ToLower()` methods for more reliable comparison

    if (student == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    return View(student);
}
```

Hope this helps.